# How do I not regenerate the .manifest file for my C# VS2013 project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a C# solution in Visual Studio 2013, and every time I run it, it generates a `Brilliance.exe.manifest` file. I would like this file to not be generated every time I build and debug my application. My application's name is "Brilliance"

In my project settings I tried setting the "Icon and manifest" option for Manifest to be both `Embed manifest with default settings` and `Create application without a manifest` and neither seem to have any effect.

There is no file by this name in the solution, and I don't know why it is being created.

Edit: Updated full manifest name

Comment: Which VS 2013 update? "Without a manifest" works for me in Update 4.

Comment: Hmm, I think you got the filename wrong.  Use Project > Properties > Debug tab > untick "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process".  You can now delete the vshost files, including the .manifest file, and they won't come back.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I just updated to Update 5, and "Create application without a manifest" is still creating Brilliance.exe.manifest. Also, HansPassant I have tried unticking "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" and my manifest is still being created